# Triage Queue: Duplicates without answer

Tags: discussion, triage

This question here: [how to convert a log4j generated text based .log file to a structured .xml based log file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997416/is-there-any-api-available-to-convert-a-log4j-generated-text-based-log-file-to)

merely consists of linking to another (old) question which is identical but does not yet have an answer.

My first idea would be to choose "Unsalvageable" and flag as "Duplicate", but this flag clearly says in its description:

> This question has been asked before **and already has an answer**

where the latter is just not true.

How to handle such "questions" which are just "bumps" for old, unanswered (but valid) questions?

Comment: I believe you should mod flag as mods can close post as dupes even if they are unanswered.

Comment: It's unfortunate that the old one [has not been vacuumed up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). The comments are keeping it alive.

Comment: It's a non-issue as it isn't actually a duplicate. The suggested target asks how to do the thing, while the suggested duplicate asks for a tool to do the thing. The suggested duplicate is off-topic, plain and simple.

Comment: @TinyGiant: given that the question is too broad and poorly stated anyway, this is splitting hairs, but: I disagree that asking for an API is the same as asking for _"a book, tool, software library, tutorial, or other off-site resource"_. The question is tagged Java and log4j, and assuming the API being requested is in fact contained in those frameworks, the question would amount to a "how to do it", and not a "find me a tool to do it". Indeed, many "how to" questions boil down to "what class or method in the framework do I need to use?" and not "find me an off-set resource".

Comment: If it were to ask how to do the thing, it would be a duplicate of the target. It doesn't though. It asks for an API to do the thing. That _is_ asking for an off-site resource @PeterDuniho. If it asked for an example of how to use a given API to do the thing, that would not be an off-site resource request because they would have already identified the off-site resource that they would like to use.

Comment: If the new question were a good and complete one in its own right, then there would be no reason to close it.  In fact, it could be beneficial because a question as old as the one referenced in this case is unlikely ever to be answered, but if the new one got a good answer then the old one could be closed as a dupe.  With just a link to the old question, however, I would downvote and ask for a self-contained question, or I would close vote if the original question does not meet our current standards.